# view all the show/hide divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got this show/hide div working well:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#list1">List 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#list2">List 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">View All</a></li>
</ul>


<div class="content">
    <div class="list current" id="list1"> Test 1</div>
     <div class="list" id="list2">Test 2</div>
</div>
```

Shown here:
**[Show/Hide and View All](http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/39eBk/1/)**

What I can't figure out is how can I do the **View ALL** using the method jquery I have (I have it blank)?

I was thinking `.show` but just cant figure the best method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just need the following addition:

```
var selector = link === '#' ? '.content .list' : link;
var showIt = $(selector);
```

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/39eBk/4/

Comment: Excellent this is exactly what I was looking for - Flawless!

Comment: can the height be control?...looks like when going to a smaller div the height stays to the biggest

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as `viewall` method. But you can use all the elements and show them!

```
if(link == '#') {
   // show all the links!
}
```

Note the `#`, since you are getting the `href` of the hyperlink and then showing the lists. You can get the value and do an `if else` block and after that you can show them all at one time!

Comment: Thank you so much you have a good point though the answer was given I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/39eBk/6/)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<li><a href="#all" id="all">View All</a></li>
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".menu a").not('#all').click(function () { //not handle id a tag with id all
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        var showIt = $(link);
        var hideIt = $(".list.current");

        hideIt.fadeOut(100, function () {
            hideIt.removeClass("current");
            showIt.addClass("current");
            showIt.fadeIn(100);
        });
    });
    $('#all').click(function () { // handle a tag with id all
        $(".content > div").fadeIn(100).addClass("current"); show all div under class content and add class current
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks this is the way I tried but clicking back to 1 or 2 didn't hide all

Comment: Yes I see it now thank you! I appreciate your answer I had to give it to jmar777 since his was good also but thank you I will credit you.

Answer (score 1):

As you are effectively using the `href` as a JQuery selector then you can just set the View All `href` to the class selector `.list`:

```
<a href=".list">View All</a>
```

It is also important to prevent the default behavior of the link:

```
$(".menu a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //...
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/h5ks9/)

Personally though I would prefer not to use the `href` for storing anything other than what it is meant for, so perhaps using `data-*` attributes is better:

```
<li><a href="#list2" data-selector="#list2">List 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-selector=".list">View All</a></li>
```

and then...

```
$(".menu a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).data("selector");
    //...
```

[Here it is in action](http://jsfiddle.net/h5ks9/1/)

Comment: thanks @musefan this is also correct I had to credit jmar777 since thats the first I saw. But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example without the jQuery animations. CSS3 Transition FTW!

http://jsfiddle.net/brendonparker/39eBk/8/

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(".menu a").click(function() {
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        var showIt = $(link);
        var hideIt = $(".list.current");
        if(link == '#'){
            $('.content .list').addClass('current');
            return;
        } else {
            $('.content .list').removeClass('current');
            $(link).addClass('current');
        }    
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#list1">List 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#list2">List 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#list3">List 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">View All</a></li>
</ul>


<div class="content">
    <div class="list current" id="list1"> Test 1</div>
     <div class="list" id="list2">Test 2</div>
    <div class="list" id="list3">Test 3</div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu {list-style: none !important; margin: 0 !important; overflow: hidden;}
.list {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    opacity: 0; 
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;}
.list.current {
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;}
.menu li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 .6em;
    line-height: .8em !important;
}
```